# ASCII compatibles and not compatibles characters encoding

Tags: encoding, ascii

What is an example of a character encoding which is not compatible with ASCII and why isn't it?

Also, what are other encoding which have upward compatibility with ASCII (except UTF and ISO8859, which I already know) and for what reason?

Comment: What do you mean by compatible? Reading text written with one character set and encoding and reading it with the _wrong_ one? Also, what do you mean by UTF? If you read ASCII as UTF-16 or UTF-32, you'd likely get decoding errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are EBCDIC-based encodings that are not compatible with ASCII.  For example, I recently encountered an email that was encoded using **CP1026**, aka [EBCDIC 1026](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?name=CP1026).  If you look at its character table, letters and numbers are encoded at very different offsets than in ASCII.  This was throwing off my email parser particularly because `LF` is encoded as 0x25 instead of as 0x0A in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, any example of other forward compatible encoding ?

Comment: Most commonly used encodings are completely ASCII-compatible (ISO8859-X/Latin-X, GB 18030, Big5, etc), or at least are *mostly* compatible with ASCII (SHIFT-JIS, etc). EBCDICs are rare nowadays.

Comment: Shift-JIS is a tricky one, because `¥` lives at `0x5c` where `\` would usually be.

Comment: @CraigRinger Shift-Jis also has an overline (U+203E) character at 0x7E in place of `'~'`. And then there is the ISO-2022 encodings, which use ASCII escape sequences to switch between single-byte and multi-byte modes.